# How to protect pure functions

Tags: pure-function

I have some pattern functions and pure function in my package. If i set attributes `Protected` and `ReadProtected`. My pattern function definition is hidden from end user but for pure function just evaluating its name prints its definition. I believe pure function are storing their definition as `OwnValues` as opposed to `DownValues`. Is there a way i can make them available for use but hide their definition?

Comment: Yes and no. You can do this: `f = Function[x, x^2];
SetAttributes[f, ReadProtected];
?? f` and you see that also the `OwnValues` of `f` are hidden from `Definition` and `FullDefinition`. But `f` will always evaluate to a `Function` and of course, one can see what it does.

Comment: So it means i have to rewrite all my pure functions as patterns. Also can someone confirm if any of the builtin functions are written as pure functions.

Comment: Note that `ReadProtected` does not really protect from reading. My favorite example is ``Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];PrintDefinitions[HighlightGraph]``.